# 8085 Microprocessors. Opcode needs user argument. Using GNUSim8085

Tags: assembly, opcode, 8085

```
LXI H  ; "Load HL with 4000H"
MVI M  ; "Store 32H in memory location pointed by HL register pair (4000H)"
HLT    ; "Terminate program execution"
```

Its an 8085 microprocessor code, intended to store 8 data in memory.

However when I run the code, I come across a Error.

Error :   line 1 : Opcode needs an User Argument. (this is the assembler message).

Can someone show me the mistake I am making and help me through.

I am using GNUSim8085.

Comment: Where are you supplying the address(4000H) and data(32H)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should typically start by consulting an instruction set reference when you get such errors. Searching for *"8085 LXI"* yielded:

> Load register pair immediate
>   `LXI Reg. pair, 16-bit data` The instruction loads 16-bit data in the register pair
>   designated in the operand.
>   Example: `LXI H, 2034H` or `LXI H, XYZ`

So based on your comment *"`; "Load HL with 4000H`"* I'm guessing that you meant to write:

```
LXI H, 4000H
```